# tar.7z e_fail when compressing Backup

Tags: linux, compression, tar, 7zip

I run a monthly backup of our NAS using rysnc on centos linux. into a folder called Monthly backup. i then want to compress this folder so i can keep 2 or 3 months archives.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

# Monthly_Compress
7zip a /home/backup/files/backupmonthly/monthly_$(date +%y%m%d).7z /home/backup/files/backupfull
```

This is the script i run using crontab.

the process starts fine and runs for an hour or two and then i get this on the terminal

```
0%/home/backup/files/backupfull/home/everyone/Xari/2014-04-01_120546515.mp4

System error:
E_FAIL
[root@prod-01 backup]#
```

any ideas??

Comment: `/home/backup/files/backupmonthly/monthly_$(date +%y%m%d).7z` must be created, right , please share the size of the same.
On 32 bit systems 4Gig is the max filesize(for one file)

Comment: # uname -i
x86_64

# ls -s monthly_140422.tar.7z
ls: cannot access monthly_140422.tar.7z: No such file or directory
# ls -s
total 4
4 montly_140422.tar.7z?
#